# How do I make a generalized function, which could be used for any column in the dataset?

Tags: python, function, data-analysis, data-cleaning

[image]

```
def func1(dframe,Country,column_list,Role):

    dframe1 = dframe[dframe.Country == Country]          
    dframe1 = dframe1[column_list]                      
    dframe1 = dframe1[dframe1.age != 2019]
    dframe1 = dframe1[(dframe1["Role"]==Role)]           
    dframe1 = int(round(dframe1.loc[:,"age"].mean()))
    return dframe1
```

I defined this function where the first line extracted rows where Country column's data matched with the Country passed, however how do I generalize this. Like if I want to extract data on the bases of the Gender column value.
How do I pass an argument where instead of dframe.Country I can use dframe.(passed argument)?

What are the ways do apply one cleaning function to multiple columns in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive answer to your question would be to use `operator.attrgetter`, which returns a function that you can apply to `df`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def extract_rows(df, column_name, value):
    return df[attrgetter(column_name)(df) == value]
```

However, in general, I would prefer using *bracket syntax* for `pandas`, since that does everything dot notation can and more besides. Accordingly, this would work:

```
def extract_rows(df, column_name, value):
    return df[df[column_name] == value]
```